# How to make character not slide down hill in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-engine, game-development, unity3d-editor

we made a character with a capsule collider and a ladder (smooth as a slide collider) and the character is not fixed in the middle of the stairs but just slips off.

I tried to create a physical material for the character (with friction force) did not help

Comment: You can make it so gravity is always applied in the direction of the ground, instead of always down. Disable the Rigidbody's gravity, and apply the forces on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your character touches the ground you can deactivate the gravity affects for the rigidbody using [Rigidbody.useGravity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-useGravity.html).

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, but I have already solved this problem, it turned out I just needed the same physical material (which I added to the player) on the ladder's ridgitbody and it worked

Comment: If you've found your own solution you can post it as an answer. Don't feel obligated to accept someone else's answer.